# How to make AngularJS Material Grid List span horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

The demo is here: [Angular Material Grid List](https://material.angularjs.org/#/demo/material.components.gridList).

When the elements overflow, they would be rearranged vertically. Is it possible to make them horizontal? It seems that make elements stack horizontally is always harder than vertically in web programming.